# Cardview, cardCornerRadius not working

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm trying to set to my cards a `cardCornerRadius` but its not working.

Take a look my code below:

**CardView** where the last property is the `cardCornerRadius`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/user_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
```

**Dependencies**

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
>   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
>   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'

I didn't get any error in the console, so I really don't know what is happening.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: what devices are you running it? I think it wont work on pre lollipop devices

Comment: I have tried in a nexus 5 with lollipop & nexus 6p with marshmallow @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: Try removing the foreground

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you may be using`setBackgroundColor` in your code.

If so, try to use `setCardBackgroundColor` instead.

Comment: Good answer. Any explanation of why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 1):

use `card_view:cardCornerRadius="x"`